# Visual Studio report designer wrong page size

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc

I've created a report with just 1 tablix with fixed page size of 4cmx20cm.

This is my report's property :

[image: Report's property]

This is my tablix's property:

[image]

When I print this (even in the preview) the width is always 4,6cm. Always. If I put my size in the property to 3,4cm the reports then have the right width of 4cm.

What am I missing ?